# Is this sequence significant?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm doing some algorithmic work and stumbled onto a strange pattern.  Does anyone know if this is some common thing? (like does this converge towards the gaussian curve perhaps??)

starting with:
1,3,3,1
I offset it to the right one value and add it to itself
1,3+1,3+3,1+3,1=
1,4,6,4,1

continuing that same algorithm it then spits out this:
1,5,10,10,5,1

then:
1,6,15,20,15,6,1

then:
1,7,21,35,35,21,7,1

then:
1,8,28,56,70,56,28,8,1

Look familiar to anyone, or anyone see what the pattern is converging on?

Here's a link to the last set of values, plotted in wolfram alpha
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2C8%2C28%2C56%2C70%2C56%2C28%2C8%2C1
Thanks!!

Comment: This is the same idea as the construction of the Pascal triangle, just starting from a more general form than the initial "$(1,1)$" used for that triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found the [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom nk$. When you order them in a triangle you get [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle). you can calculate them with [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for large $n$. Have a look at the proof of the site [de Moivre–Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem). Finally you will get

$\binom nk \approx \frac{2^n\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \exp\left(-\frac{(2k-n)^2)}{2n}\right)$

(Here I have set $p=q=\tfrac 12$)

Comment: If you treated a row of pascal's triangle as an N dimensional vector, and normalized the vector (so the graph just got "more refined" as N got larger), does pascals triangle converge on a significant shape?  I can ask a new question for this if you think it's warranted.  Thanks!!

Comment: Which norm do you want to use for the vector?

Comment: good question... i guess actually maybe just dividing all numbers by the peak value, so the peak is always at 1?  wondering if that is starting to look gaussian... :P

Comment: @AlanWolfe: When you divide the vector by $2^n$ which is the length of the vector under the [1-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) you will get a normal distribution (this is actually what is proved in de-Moivre-Laplace theorem). Have a look also at the [Central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) – de-Moivre-Laplace  is a special case of the Central limit theorem...

Comment: thank you so much, that is so informative and useful! (:

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is Pascal's Triangle.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle